# vscode git not working "folder currently does not have a git repository"

Tags: apt, git, visual-studio-code

vscode:  I cannot see anything in my git panel for vscode.
vscode integration for git does not work.
When I open up my old git directory on my data drive, it says:

> the folder has no git and cannot initialize with vscode.

I have installed ubuntu many times now. Removed all ppa. Although it does work with a clean install of just vscode and git, when I install other items, git fails. These are standard repo items, android studio or mainstream browser debs.

from apt I installed:

```
sudo apt install vlc blender ardour calf-plugins calibre kate kdeconnect wine hugo sigil inkscape gimp synaptic caja okular kdenlive handbrake gparted caffeine gnome-shell-extensions  gnome-tweaks
```

I also installed these debs googlechrome, vivaldi, vscode
I also ran android-studio install setup
I also have path setup for flutter but did not install with doctor yet.

git with vscode works with gdebi vscode and git installed.
When I come back to my computer after the larger installs as stated above.. git does not work with vscode integration.

Answer (score 0):

windows dual boot.  Need to fully shut down